# What is the difference between in-use volume and available in EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the difference between in-use volume and available volume in EBS volume?
I am able to see I have 5 instances and their respective 5 volumes in-use, apart from that I am able to see some volumes as Available under EBS volume. My EBS charges are applying it is not showing any ec2 instance connected with those available, so can I delete those 'Available' volumes?

Answer (score 3):

**In-use** means it that the Amazon EBS volume is attached to an Amazon EC2 instance.

**Available** means that the volume is *not* attached to an Amazon EC2 instance.

You can certainly delete the *available* volumes, but it is up to you to know what is stored on those volumes and whether you need to retain the data.

Comment: Thanks John, this makes sense...My understanding is also same but wants to confirm from some high experienced guy in aws. ..If I delete it it won't impact any running instances in that case..correct me if I am wrong. That was created long back from snapshots or ami i believe but not in use.

Comment: Correct. Deleting an _available_ EBS volume will not impact any running EC2 instances.

Comment: Does "in-use" explicitly mean attachment.status = "attached" or can it also mean "attaching" or "detaching"? I haven't been able to find explicit docs on this yet.